¿Como Puedo Hacer Que un Servicio de windows echo en .net6 ejecute una aplicacion windowsform?
Actualmente estoy desarrollando un proyecto de tipo servicio, debe ejecutar otro proyecto que es una ventana. solo que cuando registro el servicio y lo inicio, al ejecutar la aplicacion desde el servicio se ejecuta en segundo plano y no muestra el formulario que deberia cargar. aqui les pongo el codigo que estoy usando.
cosas que he intentado
Modificar las propiedades de la ventana después de la creación
ejecucion de un programa de consola intermedio que ejecute la aplicacion de ventana.(los 2 quedan en segundo plano)

//CODIGO SERVICIO

using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Principal;

public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private List<string> _procesos = new List<string>();
        private readonly string MessageFile = @"C:\FingelLog.log";
        
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            //SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
        }
        
        public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(MessageFile, $"Comenzo Servicio:{Environment.UserName}--{WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name}\n");
// INTENTO EJECUTAR EL PROGRAMA DE VENTANA DESDE UNA CONSOLA
            Process.Start(@"F:\Proyectos\IntermediateSrv\bin\Debug\net6.0\IntermediateSrv.exe");
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }    
        
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var miapp = "SeguimientoServicio";

            File.AppendAllText(MessageFile, $"Ejecutando Servicio:{Environment.UserName}--{WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name}\n");
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EJECUTANDO SERVICIO.......................");
//AQUI INTENTO EJECUTARLO DESDE EL SERVICIO Y SOLO LO CARGA AL SEGUNDO PLANO
                    Process.Start("F:\\Proyectos\\SeguimientoServicio\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\SeguimientoServicio.exe");
                
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(100000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }  
    }

//Codigo Programa de consola Intermedio que ejecuta el programa de ventana

using IntermediateSrv;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using static IntermediateSrv.SystemEventsWin32;


// Importar funciones de la API de Windows
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int ShellExecuteEx([In] ShellExecuteInfo info);

// Constantes para mostrar la ventana
const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEventsWin32.SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;

Console.WriteLine($"HOLAA MUNDO");
var Procesos = new ProcessData();
var archivoLog = new ArchivoLog();

archivoLog.Escribir($"USUARIO AUTENTICADO -----{Environment.UserName}\n");

foreach (var Proceso in Procesos.GetCurrentProcesses())
    archivoLog.Escribir($"{Proceso.Id}-----{Proceso.ProcessName}\n");

//Console.ReadLine();
int idproceso = 0;



var separadordelinea = "**********************************************************************\n";

var msg = $"---------------------Ejecutando Aplicacion-----------------------------\n";
msg += "F:\\Proyectos\\SeguimientoServicio\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\SeguimientoServicio.exe";
archivoLog.Escribir(msg);


////////////////////////Ejecutar aplicacion//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "F:\\Proyectos\\2024\\FingerVerifyService\\SeguimientoServicio\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\SeguimientoServicio.exe",
    //UseShellExecute = true, // Usar el shell del sistema
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
//Console.ReadLine();
*/
/// INTENTA ABRIR LA APLICACION Y SOLO LA CARGA AL SEGUNDO PLANO
Process newProcess = Process.Start("F:\\Proyectos\\SeguimientoServicio\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0-windows\\SeguimientoServicio.exe");
newProcess.WaitForInputIdle(); // Esperar a que el proceso esté listo
IntPtr mainWindowHandle = newProcess.MainWindowHandle;
ShowWindow(mainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWNORMAL); // Mostrar la ventana

/// mostrar una ventana  POR ALGUNA RAZON NO LO SACA DEL SEGUNDO PLANO Y NO SE MUESTRA LA VENTANA
Process processes = Process.GetProcessById(idproceso);
if (processes != null)
{
    Process targetProcess = processes;
    // Obtener el identificador de la ventana principal del proceso
    IntPtr hWnd = targetProcess.MainWindowHandle;
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);

    // Traer la ventana al primer plano
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
}

// ESTA ES OTRA ALTERNATIVA Y TAMPOCO LO SACA DEL SEGUNDO PLANO
var info = new ShellExecuteInfo
{
    cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ShellExecuteInfo)),
    fMask = 0x00000040, // SEE_MASK_NOASYNC
    lpVerb = "open",
    lpFile = "SeguimientoServicio.exe"
};

int result = ShellExecuteEx(info);

if (result <= 32)
{
    archivoLog.Escribir($"Error al abrir la aplicación: {result}");
}

